# How to add custom JNDI properties into Bluemix Mobile Foundation Service

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

We are developing MobileFirst 8.0 Cordova Application and hosting it on Bluemix cloud using Mobile Foundation Service. Here in our project we have couple of URL's which tries to read/write data from customer's server's. So we need to add those URL's as JNDI properties in server configuration and retrieve those properties using "getServerJNDIProperty". So the question is there any chance that we can add custom JNDI properties? If yes, how can we configure new JNDI properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure custom JNDI properties in the "Server Configuration" table of the Mobile Foundation service on Bluemix.  An example of this is discussed [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/11/analytics-bm-service) - the blog post I have linked to talks about using this capability to configure Mobile Analytics, but you can generalize the method to add your own custom JNDI properties.